How to style "Namespace" in a "Class Diagram" in Mermaid?
In Mermaid, we can define a class such as EnumMap to be an object in our Class Diagram.
class EnumMap { }

We can style that object by using style command.
style EnumMap color : SeaGreen

Furthermore, we can group multiple objects together within a box, called a Namespace.
namespace special {
    class EnumMap { }
    class TreeMap { }
}

That results in a box drawn around those objects. That box has a thin black line.
 How do I change the color of that line to something other than black? How do I fill that "namespace" box?

This post meets the criteria to be classified as a good question. I do not see a reason for the downvote.

The Mermaid styling options for class diagrams seem to apply only to the nodes, not the namespaces.
However, analysis of the generated SVG reveals that the <rect> representing the namespace is embedded in a <g id="special">. This allows you to override its attributes with additional CSS rules (analogous to Mermaid style color/fill/stroke of an entity or attribute in ER diagram):


<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs"></script>
<pre class="mermaid">
---
config:
  themeCSS: |
    #special rect {
      stroke: red !important;
      fill: yellow !important;
    }
---
classDiagram
  namespace special {
    class EnumMap { }
    class TreeMap { }
  }
</pre>



This works only because the <rect>s representing the classes are not descendants of <g id="special"> but there is an intervening <foreignObject>. Otherwise, the classes would be affected by my CSS rule as well; and if I use the more precise selector #special > rect, the CSS rule does not "survive" the Mermaid-to-HTML transformation.
The limits of the CSS rules approach clearly show up here. But if it is just for one effect, you may get by with it.
